# Calculate total count of int values in dictionary

Tags: c#, linq

I'm still finding my feet in the c# world and I've recently been looking at Linq. My question is:

I have a dictionary which holds a userID and a list of integer values (game scores). I was wondering if it would be possible to get the overall count for each user?

```
var scoreDictionary = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();
```

Example, 
     Key = 1234
     Value = {23,25,35,13,57,32}

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want a lookup table from the user-id to

...the *number* of scores for the user:

```
scoreDictionary.ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value.Count)
```

...the *sum* of scores for the user:

```
scoreDictionary.ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value.Sum())
```

By the way, you may also consider using the [`ILookup<,>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534291%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) interface to represent the multi-map you have there instead of a `Dictionary<,>` with a collection as `TValue`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Sum` method.

Not sure what you want to do with each total. This will output each user's total score:

```
foreach (var user in scoreDictionary)
{
    Console.WriteLine(
        "User {0} has a total score of {1}", user.Key, user.Value.Sum());
}
```

You could also create a new dictionary to store the values in:

```
var scores = scoreDictionary.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value.Sum());
```

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
foreach(var item in scoreDictionary)
{
    Console.WriteLine("User " + item.Key " + has a score of " + item.Value.Sum());
}
```

This would print like this

```
User 1234 has a score of 185
User 5678 has a score of 252
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

List has a count property, so you can get the number of scores for a given player (whose id is stored in 'playerId') this way:

```
int playerScoreCount = scoreDictionary[playerId].Count;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code .Hope this will help .

```
var scores = scoreDictionary.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value.Sum());
```